# Counting the dead pixel by using multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pixel, python-multiprocessing, counting

I have no idea how counting the dead pixels with multiprocessing works I got it so far without multiprocessing and analyzing the 10 pictures we need to analyze takes around 7 minutes...

```
import random
import time

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, current_process, freeze_support
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image1 = Image.open('MA_HA1_drawing_0.png')
image2 = Image.open('MA_HA1_drawing_1.png')
image2 = Image.open('MA_HA1_drawing_2.png')
image3 = Image.open('MA_HA1_drawing_3.png')
image4 = Image.open('MA_HA1_drawing_4.png')
image5 = Image.open('MA_HA1_drawing_5.png')
image6 = Image.open('MA_HA1_drawing_6.png')
image7 = Image.open('MA_HA1_drawing_7.png')
image8 = Image.open('MA_HA1_drawing_8.png')
image9 = Image.open('MA_HA1_drawing_9.png')

def analyze_picture(image):
    time.sleep(0.5*random.random())
    counter = 0
    for x in range(616,6446):
        for y in range(756,3712):
            r,g,b = image.getpixel((x,y))

            if r != 1 and g != 1 and b != 1:
                counter += 1
    return counter

def test():
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 4
    TASKS1 = [(analyze_picture(image1))]
    TASKS2 = [(analyze_picture(image2))]
    TASKS3 = [(analyze_picture(image2))]
    TASKS4 = [(analyze_picture(image3))]
    TASKS5 = [(analyze_picture(image4))]
    TASKS6 = [(analyze_picture(image5))]
    TASKS7 = [(analyze_picture(image6))]
    TASKS8 = [(analyze_picture(image7))]
    TASKS9 = [(analyze_picture(image8))]
    TASKS10 = [(analyze_picture(image9))]

    print TASKS1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    test()
```

and they gave us some functions to understand multiprocessing and use it for our task but I don't understand them and have no idea how to use them.

```
def worker(input, output):
    for func, args in iter(input.get, 'STOP'):
        result = calculate(func, args)
        output.put(result)

def calculate(func, args):
    result = func(*args)
    return '%s says that %s%s = %s' % \
        (current_process().name, func.__name__, args, result)

def mul(a, b):
    time.sleep(0.5*random.random())
    return a * b

def plus(a, b):
    time.sleep(0.5*random.random())
    return a + b

 # Create queues
    task_queue = Queue()
    done_queue = Queue()

    # Submit tasks
    for task in TASKS1:
        task_queue.put(task)

    # Start worker processes
    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
        Process(target=worker, args=(task_queue, done_queue)).start()
        print i

    # Get and print results
    print 'Unordered results:'
    for i in range(len(TASKS1)):
        print '\t', done_queue.get()

    # Add more tasks using `put()`
    for task in TASKS2:
        task_queue.put(task)

    # Get and print some more results
    for i in range(len(TASKS2)):
        print '\t', done_queue.get()

    # Tell child processes to stop
    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
        task_queue.put('STOP')
        print 'process ', i, ' is stopped'
```

EDIT: New Code

```
import random
import time

from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, current_process, freeze_support
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def worker(input, output):
    for func, args in iter(input.get, 'STOP'):
        result = calculate(func, args)
        output.put(result)

def calculate(func, args):
    result = func(args)
    return '%s says that %s%s has %s dead pixels\n' % \
        (current_process().name, func.__name__, args, result)

def analyze_picture(image_name):
    t1 = time.clock()
    image = Image.open(image_name)
    time.sleep(0.5*random.random())
    counter = 0
    for x in range(616,6446):
        for y in range(756,3712):
            r,g,b = image.getpixel((x,y))

            if r != 1 and g != 1 and b != 1:
                counter += 1

    t2 = time.clock()
    dt = t2 - t1
    print '\tThe process takes ',dt,' seconds.\n Result:\n'
    return counter

def test():


    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 4

    TASKS1 = [(analyze_picture, image_names[i]) for i in range(10)]

    print TASKS1

    # Create queues
    task_queue = Queue()
    done_queue = Queue()

    # Submit tasks
    for task in TASKS1:
        task_queue.put(task)

    # Start worker processes
    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
        Process(target=worker, args=(task_queue, done_queue)).start()
        print i

    # Get and print results
    print 'Unordered results:'
    for i in range(len(TASKS1)):
        print '\t', done_queue.get()

    # Tell child processes to stop
    for i in range(NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES):
        task_queue.put('STOP')
        print 'process ', i, ' is stopped'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_names =[('MA_HA1_drawing_'+str(i)+'.png') for i in range(10)]
    freeze_support()
    test()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind multiprocessing:

- Create several workers which can be distributed to different cores for execution in parallel.
- For multi*process*ing these workers are processes with their separate memory space (in contrast to threads).
- Due to the separate memory space they can not communicate (receive a task and send its result) via the memory. As a result, queues for inter-process communications are needed.
- Now, the tasks are distributed to the workers via the queues.
- Finally, the results are collected which the workers have sent via the queues.

If it is mandatory to use the posted code you can do it as follows:

1. Create queues
2. Start worker processes
3. Submit tasks
   It is very import to submit the tasks **after** the workers were created. It is possible, that the buffer of the queue gets full and blocks until something was taken from it, but as long as there is no worker yet, nothing is taken from the queue --> DEADLOCK.
   Since you want to do all the images in parallel, your `TASKS1` (recognize the plural) has to be `[(analyze_picture, (analyze_picture(image1),), (analyze_picture, (analyze_picture(image2),), ...]` (`worker` expects a tuple of the function and the arguments as a tuple itself).
4. Get and print results
5. Tell child processes to stop

Probably that's what you was asking about.

After all, there are three further aspects of improving performance (and code readability):

- Inter-process communication is quite expensive. Hence, you should minimize the data which is transfered from and to the workers.
  In your case, this means to pass the image name only instead of the entire image. Additionally, this leads to a parallel read in of all the images because the workers read the images.
- All the worker stuff is already implemented in [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool), which reduces the lines of code for the multiprocessing to two:
  `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES)
  result = pool.map(analyze_picture, [image1, image2, ...])`
- Last but not least, iterating pixel by pixel is rather slow. With NumPy (or the higher level SciPy) you can accelerate it a lot.

Finally, your script could look like the following and will be much faster than 7 minutes:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc

def analyze_picture(imagename):
    image = misc.imread(imagename)    # image[y, x, r/g/b]
    return len(np.argwhere( (a[756:,616:,0]!=1) & (a[756:,616:,1]!=1) & (a[756:,616:,2]!=1) ))

def main():
    pool = mp.Pool()                  # default: number of logical cores
    result = pool.map(analyze_picture, ( "MA_HA1_drawing_{}.png".format(i)
                                            for i in range(10) ))
    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    main()
```

I am not sure about how your images look like (the `{r,g,b}!=1` is strange) but in the [reference of `scipy.misc.imread`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) you'll find the appropriate mode for you image.

Comment: hey @Chickenmarkus thank you very much for your fast answer in detail. I appreciate it and I tried it before you send me your answer and I got it work but now I have another problem the result is like this https://pastebin.com/gsviTkLj
but I wanted it like 
the process takes x seconds
Result 
Image x has x dead pixels
and not 
the process takes x seconds 
Result
the process takes x seconds ...
i will edit my question with the new code so you can see where maybe is the problem

Comment: The `print`ing of the time in `analyze_picture()` and the `print`ing of the result in `test()` are running asynchronously because of the multiprocessing. The workers should usually not print something (because of the indeterministic asynchronism and there are usually many many workers). Let the worker just return the values (or strings) and print it only in the main process `test()`, instead.